# Unable to Auth Twitter V2 to access Followers data. I have basic Subscription

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

1. Unable to Authenticate using Tweepy for Twitter V2
2. Unable to get follower data. IF any one used Twitter V2 Basic Version for getting followers details.
3. Tried with from pytwitter import Api also even in that unable to authenticate.
4. Tried both tweepy client and api.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.